# Connect database in phonegap

Tags: android, database, cordova

I have created the User interface in phonegap for android. And now I want to insert data in my web based application which is made using php and mysql. So whenever I click on submit button then the information should be stored on the web database of my web application.
How can I achieve this...?

Comment: With [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: refer- http://samcroft.co.uk/2012/posting-data-from-a-phonegap-app-to-a-server-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

You also can store your information using session storage and ajax.

```
formData = {
    username: $("#username").val(),
    password: $("#password").val()
}
$.ajax({
    url: "https://example.com/login.php",
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: formData,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("userId", data.user[0].userId);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```